# How to change default c++ standand library path

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I had installed gcc5.3 in my own path, $HOME/gcc/gcc5.3.0.
and build project successfully. but when running, this error occurred:

```
../../lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by ../../lightgbm)
../../lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ../../lightgbm)
../../lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ../../lightgbm)
../../lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ../../lightgbm)
../../lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ../../lightgbm)
../../lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by ../../lightgbm)
../../lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by ../../lightgbm)
```

and LD_LIBRARY_PATH had also set. $HOME/gcc/gcc5.3.0/lib

and command: ldd lightgbm

```
./lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by ./lightgbm) ./lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./lightgbm) ./lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ./lightgbm) ./lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./lightgbm) ./lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./lightgbm) ./lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by ./lightgbm) ./lightgbm: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by ./lightgbm)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcc077d000)
        /$LIB/libonion.so => /lib64/libonion.so (0x00007f773717d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7736d5c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7736ad8000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f77368cb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f77366b5000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7736498000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7736104000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7737062000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7735f00000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7735cf8000)
```

what should I do to change lddstd++.so.6 library path to $HOME/gcc/gcc5.3.0/lib?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/lib:/usr/local/gcc-5.2.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`